# Why do I get Cors error when using dotnet publish command line?

Tags: .net-6.0, publish

I'm using VS 2022 to deploy a dotnet 6 web api.
I downloaded a publish profile from my shared hosting account and use the one-click publish button and it works perfectly.

However, I'm trying to automate the process, and when I run the dotnet publish command it says it published successfully and updated the files. However, when I try to login or call the API, it returns 500 status.

Access to XMLHttpRequest at '**Endpoint***' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I tried adding 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' to the angular app even though it works without it when I publish manually but still no go.

Is VS2022 running any other command besides the one below?

This is the command I use.

dotnet publish project.csproj /p:PublishProfile=profileName.pubxml /p:Password=

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many trials, I found the solution which makes no sense.

I added the following to the command line.

-f net6.0 -c Release

These config settings are already part of the publish profile, I guess it doesn't release those from the publish profile.